# Finding number of days between two dates SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, case

Sorry for the misunderstanding.. let me try to clear this up

I'll keep this short and thanks for the help!

I have an `age` case I want to return the number of days between current date and the import date here is my original query I am wanting to change.

Thanks again

```
age = case                
         when datediff(day, ( t.importdate), getdate()) > 365 then J - 366+
         when datediff(day, ( t.importdate), getdate()) > 270 then I - 271 to 365
         when datediff(day, ( t.importdate), getdate()) > 240 then H - 241 to 270
```

This query will group the datediff and it goes all the way down to A before it ends, this is meant just show the person the categories the datediff would fall into.

What I want to accomplish is getting rid of the grouping function but still run a case that will return the datediff to just numbers...

ex.. instead of `> 365 then J - 366+` It would just return say 18, which would be the days in between that specific instance..I am running hundreds of user accounts all with different import dates I want to compare with current date..

I hope this is clear!

Comment: your example case statement is unclear.  what is it that you're wanting to return from the case statement?  we have no idea what J, I and H are, nor what you intend to return with something like `I - 271 to 365`

Comment: If what you're looking for is the actual number of days instead of a range, get rid of all the case stuff and just keep one datediff call.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Please edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are looking to return ages in groups.  If so, this may be what you are looking for:

```
select age = (case when datediff(day, t.importdate, getdate()) > 365
                   then 'J - 366+'

                   when datediff(day, t.importdate, getdate()) > 270
                   then 'I - 271 to 365'
                   when datediff(day, t.importdate, getdate()) > 240
                   then 'H - 241 to 270'
                   else 'G - <270
              end)
```